# Why setTimeout not able to access outside specific variable?

Tags: javascript, settimeout, client-side

I have found a strange behaviour of `setTimeout`. I don't know why it is able to select some variable values properly from those declared before `setTimeout` but not a specific one.

```
this.RegisterForUpdateContents = function (intervalTime, FormControlGuid)
{        
    var layoutInfo = sessionStorage.getItem('LayoutInfo');            

    var panelName = "Panel_" + FormControlGuid;

    var timeOut = parseInt(intervalTime) * 1000;
    var self = this;

    var timeoutHandle = setTimeout(function ()
    {            
        var dashboardViewer = "dashboardViewer_" + FormControlGuid;
        console.log('Just sending callback for Update and LayoutInfo is  : ' + layoutInfo);

        var CallbackInfo = { 'selectedClientId': ClientId_HeaderSection.GetValue(), 'PanelName': panelName, 'Width': dockPanel.width, 'Height': dockPanel.height, 'dashboardViewer': dashboardViewer, 'UpdateTime': intervalTime, 'Layout': layoutInfo };  

    }, timeOut);


    sessionStorage.setItem((panelName + "|" + "Timeout"), timeoutHandle);
}
```

I can access `panelName` contents but I don't know what is happening with `layoutInfo`. `layoutInfo` always empty as `""`. But If I access inside `setTimeout` from `sessionStorage.getItem('LayoutInfo')`, it is accessible.

Does anybody know why?

**Edit**

```
$.each(keys, function (index, singlePanel)
{
  sessionStorage.setItem(singlePanel, JSON.stringify(panelRenderingInfo));
  if (UpdateTime)
      selfInstance.RegisterForUpdateContents(UpdateTime, FormControlGuid);
});

var LayoutVSClient = { 'CurrentLayout':    selectedLayout,'selectedClientValue': ClientId_HeaderSection.GetValue() };
sessionStorage.setItem('LayoutInfo', JSON.stringify(LayoutVSClient));
```

Comment: First and simplest question is: are you sure sessionStorage is holding the value you expect for that key at the time you try to retrieve it? Because you are accessing that variable. If it gives you an empty string then you did get a value, its not like it gave undefined or said that variable does not exist. And I believe if a key doesn't exist in session storage it returns null, not an empty string.

Comment: Also, to see if sessionStorage is part of the reason why this variable doesn't show what is expected in the timeout, what happens when you change that line to "var layoutInfo = 'test string';"?

Comment: No no, absolutely not,
this sessionStorage 100% have that key with corresponding correct value of 'LayoutInfo'. That's why sessionStorage.getItem('LayoutInfo') is nicely accessible with contents inside setTimeout

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just recreated your code to as close as possible in a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gr2qsxen/).

```
testTimeout = function (intervalTime, formControlGuid)
{        
    var layoutInfo = sessionStorage.getItem('LayoutInfo');            

    var panelName = "Panel_" + formControlGuid;

    var timeOut = parseInt(intervalTime) * 1000;
    var self = this;

    var timeoutHandle = setTimeout(function ()
    {            
        var dashboardViewer = "dashboardViewer_" + formControlGuid;
        console.log('Just sending callback for Update and LayoutInfo is  : ' + layoutInfo);

        var CallbackInfo = { 'selectedClientId': 'client-header-section-value', 'PanelName': panelName, 'Width': dockPanel.width, 'Height': dockPanel.height, 'dashboardViewer': dashboardViewer, 'UpdateTime': intervalTime, 'Layout': layoutInfo };  

    }, timeOut);


    sessionStorage.setItem((panelName + "|" + "Timeout"), timeoutHandle);
}

var dockPanel = { width:50, height:60 };
sessionStorage.setItem('LayoutInfo', 'layoutInfoContent');
testTimeout(2, '325609e6-51bd-4c69-9613-be0b36b7e2a1');
```

Using this example, I was unable to replicate the problem you described. Do you have a line of code present to set the `sessionStorage`? Example:

```
sessionStorage.setItem('LayoutInfo', 'layoutInfoContent');
```

**===EDIT===**

@Uston, are you able to change your newly edited code above to the following:

```
var LayoutVSClient = { 'CurrentLayout':    selectedLayout,'selectedClientValue': ClientId_HeaderSection.GetValue() };
sessionStorage.setItem('LayoutInfo', JSON.stringify(LayoutVSClient));

$.each(keys, function (index, singlePanel)
{
  sessionStorage.setItem(singlePanel, JSON.stringify(panelRenderingInfo));
  if (UpdateTime)
      selfInstance.RegisterForUpdateContents(UpdateTime, FormControlGuid);
});
```

Comment: I recognise my mistake.
I think because of not setting sessionStorage before registering the code to be called in setTimeout. It was happening.

@Ant : See edit.

Comment: Ah, I see. Just made an edit to my answer as well. Hopefully switching the order of things here can help. I'm not sure if it will break any existing functionality in your case though.

Comment: Ant : Yes editing was successfull and everything is fine...:-)
Thanks for your help and pointing to see setting of sessionStorage inside the code.

Answer (score 0):

I recognise my mistake!!

I had to set sessionStorage with LayoutInfo key before calling RegisterForUpdateContents.
@Ant : Thanks for your point.

Comment: If the solution provided helped you, please don't forget to mark it as an accepted answer. :)

Comment: I can't mark it as answer at the moment. Just waiting for another day...:-)

Comment: Oh, I meant the answer provided that includes the JsFiddle and code examples.